# wp_query search not taking keywords with together for multiple words

Tags: wp-query, search

I am using `WP_Query` to search results but this is not taking multiple words in **AND** operation.

this is my code

```
$searched_string = $_POST['search'];
$the_query = new WP_Query( 
        array( 
            'post_type' => 'press-release',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            's' => $searched_string 
        ) 
    );
```

when I searched for *apple introduces* it fetches all those results whose either title having *apple* or *introduces* or content having *apple* or *introduces*

while I want all words in a combination.

Please help thanks.

Comment: This is how WordPress searches for words! You can use this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-extended-search/) where it provide the way to choose between AND/OR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress also provide more filter to can change wp query using filters. What i need logical to use filter to override query below sample of code if this helpful for you.

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'posts_where_condition_search' );
 $wp_query = new WP_Query( 
        array( 
            'post_type' => 'press-release',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
        ) 
    );  
 remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'posts_where_condition_search' );    

 function posts_where_condition_search( $where ){

    $search_string = 'test';

    if( isset( $_POST['search']) && !empty($_POST['search']) )
    $search_string = $_POST['search'];

    if( empty($search_string) )
    return $where;
    // add your multiple condition here and write your custom filter

    $where .= " AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%$search_string%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%$search_string%'))) ";
    //$where .= " AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%$search_string%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%$search_string%'))) ";
    //$where .= " AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%$search_string%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%$search_string%'))) ";

   return $where;
}
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Filters